Reading a Real Time DB in firebase for a TableviewController
I am attempting to read a realtime db in firebase but my problem is the json is dynamic so using a swift file to define the layout isn't going to work.  I would like to use the data to update a tableview controller in the ultimate end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is what the data looks like:
{
  "Days": [
    null,
    {
      "Chap": {
        "1": "0",
        "2": "0",
        "3": "0",
        "4": "0"
      },
      "Comp": "0"
    },
    {
      "Chap": {
        "5": "0",
        "6": "0",
        "7": "0",
        "8": "0"
      },
      "Comp": "0"
    }
  ]
}

This app is for reading through a book by chapters.
Here is what I have come up with so far but it isn't working:
      for n in begChapt...endChapt {
            let myPath = "Yrly/Days/1/C/"
            let myRef2 = ref.child(firUser!).child(myPath)
            myRef2.observe(.value, with: {
                snapshot in
                let mItem = Repository(id: snapshot)
            })
        }
    }
    
    struct Repository {
        let id: Int
    }
    
    func parseRepository(id: Int) -> Repository? {
        guard let id = id[Int] as? Int else {
            print("Couldn't convert id to an Int")
            return nil
        }
        // TODO: parse the rest of the JSON...
        return Repository(id: id)
    }

Update 5/17/2024:
This is what I have tried now and it still isn't working:
for n in begChapt...endChapt {
            let myPath = "Yrly/Days/1/C/"
            let myRef2 = ref.child(firUser!).child(myPath)
            myRef2.observe(.value, with: {
                snapshot in
                for value in snapshot.children {
                    print("\(value)")
                }
            })
        }


The "snapshot" argument is a FIRDataSnapshot  which has a value property which represents the JSON at the given path. value is not a JSON; it's a representation of the JSON, i.e. here either NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary or NSArray. So, you do not have to "parse JSON", instead retrieve the value and try to obtain the values you expect.

I understand that, but since it is actually an INT and it has no defined name for the value, I'm not sure how to extract it.

When you expect value is a NSNumber, try downcast it to a NSNumber, when value is a NSDictionary, try downcast to a NSDictionary, and so forth. When you have no expectation what value could be, you should look into your data model / schema what it actually is. Or, just convert value to a string with string-interpolation: "\(value)".

I added an update but it still isn't showing me the values even with string-interpolation

You should see at least something. Set a breakpoint at the line where you print and, of course, ensure the database has been mutated, so that value changed events will be observed and the closure will be called. Also use the debugger, i.e. "po " to see what it is, or use dump(value) as a replacement for your print("\(value)") for getting a clue what the value actually is.

I'll go back and double check everything.

I have it working in part, the one problem I am still running into is firebase is setting the first day to 0 even though it is defined as a string of 1.  Not sure what is causing that.  I know that at first it was set for null but I really need to get rid of the null value.
